# Why is the Real Time Factor different in /gazebo/diagnostics topic and in the bottom toolbar in the simulation?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As you can see below, when I visualize the topic /gazebo/diagnostics, the real time factor is different than the value at the bottom of the window. Why is that?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21656/why-is-the-real-time-factor-different-in-/gazebo/diagnostics-topic-and-in-the-bottom-toolbar-in-the-simulation?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The RTF is not provided by the server, so each client calculates its own way. The GUI and the `gz stats` tool use the same math, which is based on the last 20 samples, but the `DiagnosticsManager` just does instantaneous calculation.

- [TimePanel::Update()](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/582827025ea59c832cc50e33d64a07ae13cad76a/gazebo/gui/TimePanel.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#TimePanel.cc-297) - this is the one you see on the GUI
- [StatsCommand::CB](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/582827025ea59c832cc50e33d64a07ae13cad76a/tools/gz.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#gz.cc-883) - this is the one you get from the `gz stats` command line tool
- [DiagnosticManager::Update](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/582827025ea59c832cc50e33d64a07ae13cad76a/gazebo/util/Diagnostics.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Diagnostics.cc-115) - this is the one on the `~/diagnostics` topic

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0